# How to get multiple image and its path from gallery and also I want to add validation in gallery that you can select only 9 images"?

Tags: android

How to get multiple image and its path from gallery and also I want to add validation in gallery that you can select only 9 images"?

Comment: you can implement your own gallery image chooser and you can add many validations

Comment: how to create own gallery please give me some example

Comment: read this https://www.airpair.com/android/photo-gallery-android-studio-list-fragments

Answer (score 0):

for picking mulitple images you can use:
https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

and for limiting only to 9 you may able to edit or override the library